# AJAX and Javascript: suggestions about an interface

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am looking for a correct method to create something [very similar to this](http://concierge.apple.com/reservation/us/en/techsupport/) (just click Next on that page). I would love to receive any suggestions on how this has been made.

I believe that it's all about a **DIV** wrapping many **ul**'s. When next is clicked, probably a jQuery code is showing an hidden DIV on the right, but wouldn't know how to position it. Everything clearly must be taken from a database.

Can anyone out there give me an advice? I hope this is not the kind of a thumbs-down question, as I tought this community would have been the best place to share this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: First step would be to open your browsers developer tools (f12 in IE/FF/Chrome will do it for you). Then you can inspect the elements on the page, view the javascirpt, and view the client requests to the server. This will not only give you an idea on how to layout the page, but the click events and how they send data back and forth. It will also give you the aided benefit of learning how to debug.

Comment: on clicks just use separate ajax calls to the server and replace the div content with responses

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some existing JavaScript MVC frameworks like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org), [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org), or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com), to understand some of the design patterns and philosophies behind these kinds of dynamic UIs.

They can be powerful for tools for a modern web app, especially when you have a lot of moving parts in your UI. They'll play well with your backend and datastore via AJAX, and you get nice features like "routing" which can help you do cool things with page flow, all the while keeping your JavaScript clean and concise.

Comment: I'm developing this with CI. Can it be any helpful?

Comment: Continuous Integration? Do you mean for testing? The frameworks above are all JavaScript, so you would write unit tests for whatever backend language/framework you're using (e.g. Python, RoR, PHP) as well as for your frontend JS. There's a JS testing framework called [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) which is popular.